# Operaciones con touchstart/touchend en aplicaciones móviles

Tags: javascript, html5, cordova, eventos, programación-móvil

En aplicaciones web móviles que desarrollé en el pasado, me encontré que el evento `click` no funcionaba del todo bien en algunos dispositivos y que el evento `touchstart` me daba mejor resultado (en concreto en juegos donde hay que pulsar rápido en la pantalla, donde en lugar de lanzarse el evento `click` parecía lanzar el de doble `click`).

Desde entonces desarrollé los controladores de eventos con `touchstart` en vez de `click`, pero probando una app en Chrome, me he encontrado con el siguiente mensaje en la consola de JS:

> Performing operations that require explicit user interaction on touchstart events is deprecated and will be removed in M54, around October 2016. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5649871251963904 for more details.

Que se podría traducir como:

> Realizar operaciones que requieran interacción explícita del usuario en eventos touchstart está obsoleto y será eliminado en M54, alrededor de Octubre de 2016. Ver https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5649871251963904 para más detalles.

Intenté cambiar el evento a `touchend` y recibí un mensaje similar. Visité la página enlazada y parece que es para evitar que se puedan realizar acciones (en particular se menciona algo sobre evitar abrir pop-ups desde anuncios o `iframes`, cosas que no tiene mi app).

Ahora mis preguntas:

- ¿Es esto algo que sólo afecta a Chrome o afectará también a mis aplicaciones web (con Cordova) para Android e iOS?
- ¿Con qué otro evento puedo sustituir `touchstart` para evitar problemas? Podría volver a `click`, supongo que funcionará, pero no sé si seguiré teniendo los mismos problemas que mencionaba arriba.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando creas una app Cordova esta soporta diferentes versiones de Android.
En Android 5 y superior la webview está basada en Chromium y se autoactualiza, así que este problema te va a afectar cuando actualicen a la versión 54 (van por la 52)

Pero desde Chrome 32, si usas el viewport `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`, el retraso del click debería desaparecer
 ([según este artículo del blog de desarrolladores google](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/12/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away?hl=en)), así que deberías poder usar click sin problemas en esas versiones

Para el resto de versiones de Android e iOS afectadas puedes usar la librería [fastclick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick), que arregla el problema en las versiones afectadas y no hace nada en las no afectadas

[Respuesta original en stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39488472/1351469)